# How to Add a Vertical Line inside a texbox using html and css

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

How to  Add a Vertical Line  inside a texbox   using html  and css

```html
<input type=text value=First|LastName >
```

Need that vertical bar to look like the two value are in two different textbox

Comment: I cannot see any way of somehow styling the pipe character to look a space between text boxes in a cross browser way. All text in a text box has to be the same font. You will likely need something much more complex to automatically create as many text boxes as you need or something.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt...
It's a complete hack, and I'm really not sure it's mobile-friendly..
But I thought about putting 2 elements on the same row using a `<span>` element, and then using JS to calculate how much one object needs to be moved in order to be placed ON TOP of the other.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <span>
  <input id="movedIntoMe" type="textarea" style="background: #FFF;padding-right:1em; display:inline-block;line-height:1.2em" value="bla"/>
  <input id="toBeMovedLeft" type="textarea" value="" disabled style="background:black; width:0px; border:none;"/>
  </span>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("toBeMovedLeft").style.marginLeft = Number(document.getElementById("movedIntoMe").offsetWidth) / 2 * (-1) + "px";
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks...This is what i want